# Are we running short of questions due to limited scope?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

It is been around 35+ days since we are into Beta and I am monitoring/using this site regularly. The average number of questions/day now became 4 and it was above 7 for the first ten days. I could see the drastic reduction in new incoming questions.

We have good answer ratio(>3.0) and 99% of questions at least have an answer. So I could assume we are ready to give answer for new questions. Since there is no inflow, I feel momentum is stopped. I feel this is not a good sign considering long term and graduation.

Do we need to extend our scope which includes other areas? If Yes, what topics we should include into scope?

Answer (score 14):

Our scope is already broad enough, not to mention not really well defined. The lack of questions is probably just due to a low user count. So no, we don't want to broaden the scope. What we need to do is better define our scope, not increase it.

Answer (score 13):

This evolution is very typical for a beta site — see [What is the typical growth pattern of a new beta site in the first few weeks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/227007/what-is-the-typical-growth-pattern-of-a-new-beta-site-in-the-first-few-weeks) on the main Stack Exchange meta. During the first couple of weeks, lots of people come with the questions they'd kept pent up for months. Then a bunch of them drift away, others stay around waiting for questions to answer. Growing the site takes a long time of attracting new users.

The activity during Lifehacks's first month was a lot higher than the average beta. There is no worry of Lifehacks running out of questions. If you [compare with other sites](http://stackexchange.com/sites#questionsperday), 4 questions per day is more than the slowest graduated sites and about median for a beta site, including betas that have been around for years. Some slower but viable sites get less than one question per day; that's ok if there's an engaged community producing quality content.

Lifehacks does not show any sign of running out of questions. Our major concern is the major disagreements over the site's scope.